# Pop_OS 22.04 No Wifi Adapter

Tags: wifi, drivers, pop-os

I recently updated to the most recent version of Pop OS 22.04 and, as always, am having issues with the Wifi adapter after install. I've been able to easily fix it before with

```
sudo apt install broadcom-sta-dkms
```

but this time I'm having quite a lot of trouble.

```
arash@pop-os:~$ uname -a
Linux pop-os 5.17.5-76051705-generic #202204271406~1653440576~22.04~6277a18 SMP PREEMPT Wed May 25 01 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
arash@pop-os:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi
arash@pop-os:~$ 
arash@pop-os:~$ sudo lspci | grep Network
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 02)
arash@pop-os:~$ sudo lsmod | grep iwlwifi
arash@pop-os:~$
arash@pop-os:~$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-5.17.5-76051705-generic     5.17.5-76051705.202204271406~1653440576~22.04~6277a18           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.17.5 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                     5.17.5.76051705.202204271406~1653440576~22.04~6277a18           amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
arash@pop-os:~$ sudo apt install broadcom-sta-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
broadcom-sta-dkms is already the newest version (6.30.223.271-17).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up broadcom-sta-dkms (6.30.223.271-17) ...
    Removing old broadcom-sta-6.30.223.271 DKMS files...
    Deleting module broadcom-sta-6.30.223.271 completely from the DKMS tree.
    Loading new broadcom-sta-6.30.223.271 DKMS files...
    Building for 5.17.5-76051705-generic
    Building initial module for 5.17.5-76051705-generic
    ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.17.5-76051705-generic is not supported
    Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.17.5-76051705-generic (x86_64)
    Consult /var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/6.30.223.271/build/make.log for more information.
    dpkg: error processing package broadcom-sta-dkms (--configure):
     installed broadcom-sta-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     broadcom-sta-dkms
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Not sure what else to try - does anyone have an idea?